# What's the meaning of "hashoom"?

Tags: meaning, idiom-meaning

With hashoom

What's the meaning of the word "hashoom"?
What does it mean: With hashoom ?

Comment: Where did you find this, and what makes you think it is a real word? (Please edit the answers into your question, rather than starting a conversation).

Comment: Please add context. Words are meaningless out of context.

Comment: I'm sure if you provided more context, or reproduced the sentence in your question, users would be motivated to reopen your question. I for one am curious to know exactly where you heard this.

Answer (score 2):

*Hashoom* seems to be [proper noun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_noun) having a middle eastern [origin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_name).

Thus `with Hashoom` implies:

> doing something with a person named Hashoom. (conceptualized situation)

Then there is [Hashem](http://www.betemunah.org/hashem.html) in Hebrew which can be used as a synonym for God.
Therefore, the interlocutor might have meant `with God`, if you are uncertain about the spelling.